# Joomla - Text above Contact Form

Tags: forms, joomla, module, position

You can't add text above a contact form.

I was thinking of:

- Create Article
- Create Module on *custom position (xxx)* with a contact form
- Load this module in the article with *{loadposition xxx}*

Question: ***Can I load a contact form in a module?*** How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the text to miscellaneous info (make sure your Contact component is set to show it.

On [this page](http://www.greyge.com/en/contact/1-press) you can see the result (I added "ask for the press kit");[image: See screenshot]
A css rule was added to remove the title "Miscellaneous Information" which I didn't fancy:

```
.contact-address.dl-horizontal + h2 {
    display: none;
}
```

This is achieved with neither template overrides, nor extra components: this is the configuration:
[image: Contact Manager configuration]

Comment: This is my preferred solution. How did you put 'miscellaneous info' on top? This is by default below the 'contact form'. Thanks.

Comment: I added the configuration screenshot

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for this is to use an extension, something like RS Form Pro, where you can build your own custom forms and add them into article using their content plugin.

You can find this extension here: http://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html

I've used it many times and it works great.

As a free alternative you could use Chrono forms, which you can find here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/1508/details

Comment: Thanks for reply Lodder, I've added a free alternative, which is also good, but have less functionality.

Comment: +1 for the good recommendations. I've never used RS Forms Pro, but have used ChronoForms and found it to be extremely good